# calling async function from different routes get different results

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have an async function called "teteraQueryDb()" that fetches data from a Db in a route like :/root/afolder/bfolder/file.js The function is exported like: module.exports.teteraQueryDb = teteraQueryDb

When I try to call the function from a file in the same route I do this and is succesfull:

```
const teteraProvDb = require('./readingProvTetera');

(async(teteraProvDb) =>{

    var newTeteraProvDb = await teteraProvDb.teteraQueryDb().then((te) => {return te})
    console.log(newTeteraProvDb)
    
})(teteraProvDb);
```

But doing this from the root, I can't fetch the data and I get "undefined":

```
const teteraProvDb = require('./afolder/bfolder/readingProvTetera');
(async(teteraProvDb) =>{

    var newTeteraProvDb = await teteraProvDb.teteraQueryDb().then((te) => {return te})
    console.log(newTeteraProvDb)
    
})(teteraProvDb);
```

This is the configuration of readingProvTetera.js:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const dbRoute = '../../myDb.db'

function teteraQueryDb(){

    let db = new sqlite3.Database(dbRoute, err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
    return new Promise (resolve =>{
        db.all("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tetera", (err, rows) =>{
            if(err){
                console.log("Something went wrong with the query");
            }
            resolve(rows) 
        })
    })
    db.close()
}

module.exports.teteraQueryDb = teteraQueryDb
```

Why? Am I missing somethig with the scopes?

Comment: By the way, `.then((te) => {return te})` is completely superfluous here, so just remove that. But right now it's unclear why the behavior differs between these two modules, so you probably need to [edit] your question and provide the implementation of `teteraQueryDb` if you'd like to receive an answer.

Comment: When you want to go parent folder then `../` makes the path go to parent's folder.

Answer (score 1):

`./` isn't root path but current folder path. So when you write path `./readingProvTetera` it means loading the db from current folder. And path `./afolder/bfolder/readingProvTetera` means loading the db from current folder's afolder's bfolder.

The root path can be checked by `console.log(process.env.PWD)`. So the path can be `${process.env.PWD}/afolder/bfolder/file.js`.

Comment: hey @jacokim, thanks a lot for the effort, but in this case the Db is not located in the "/afolder/bfolder" but in the "/" folder. And trying to require ${process.env.PWD}/afolder/bfolder/file.js. didn't work either. Where can I find more information about this require? After you've pointed that, I am pretty sure that the problem is there :-)

Comment: so I found out what was going on. The main problem was in the way my code was accessing to the database. As soon as I switched it to an absolute path everything started to work :-)

Comment: @error404 Hello. Happy your problem was solved. I am sorry I would be more helpful if I know how your folder looks like. Hope you have happy coding. If the answer is helpful anyway then please select my answer!